# How to mock a final class with mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a final class, something like this:

```
public final class RainOnTrees{

   public void startRain(){

        // some code here
   }
}
```

I am using this class in some other class like this:

```
public class Seasons{

   RainOnTrees rain = new RainOnTrees();

   public void findSeasonAndRain(){

        rain.startRain();

    }
}
```

and in my JUnit test class for `Seasons.java` I want to mock the `RainOnTrees` class. How can I do this with Mockito?

Comment: Mockito does not allow it, however PowerMock does.

Comment: As of Mockito 2.x, Mockito now supports mocking of final classes and methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mock final class with Mockito 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40979402/mock-final-class-with-mockito-2)

Answer (score 304, accepted):

[Mocking final/static classes/methods is possible with Mockito v2 only.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40018295/208809)

add this in your gradle file:

```
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.13.0'
```

This is not possible with Mockito v1, from the [Mockito FAQ](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ#what-are-the-limitations-of-mockito):

> What are the limitations of Mockito
>
> - Needs java 1.5+
> - Cannot mock final classes
>
> ...

Comment: This didn't work for me in Scala (with sbt modifications).

Comment: This wasn't enough for me. I also had to create src/test/resources/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker with "mock-maker-inline" in it as per https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-final

Comment: Mockito guide suggests to "replace", instead of "add", `mockito-inline` with `mockito-core`. https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#Mocking_Final

Comment: With newer versions of mockito (3+?) there is no need for this additional dependency of `mockito-inline`. Just the "org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker" file from answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40018295/1417088 is needed.

Comment: I only needed to replace `mockito-core:3.12.4` with `mockito-inline:3.12.4`. No fiddling with `MockMaker`. Maybe different versions have different idiosyncrasies.

Comment: I'm using 5.3.1, which I read online is supposed to support mocking final class by default. ... but I get runtime error: "Mockito cannot mock/spy because : - final class"

Answer (score 297):

**Mockito 2 now supports final** classes and methods!

But for now that's an "incubating" feature. It requires some steps to activate it which are described in [What's New in Mockito 2](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What%27s-new-in-Mockito-2#mock-the-unmockable-opt-in-mocking-of-final-classesmethods):

> Mocking of final classes and methods is an **incubating**, opt-in feature. It uses a combination of Java agent instrumentation and subclassing in order to enable mockability of these types. As this works differently to our current mechanism and this one has different limitations and as we want to gather experience and user feedback, this feature had to be explicitly activated to be available ; it can be done via the mockito extension mechanism by creating the file `src/test/resources/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` containing a single line:
>
> ```
> mock-maker-inline
> ```
>
> After you created this file, Mockito will automatically use this new engine and one can do :
>
> ```
>  final class FinalClass {
>    final String finalMethod() { return "something"; }
>  }
>
>  FinalClass concrete = new FinalClass(); 
>
>  FinalClass mock = mock(FinalClass.class);
>  given(mock.finalMethod()).willReturn("not anymore");
>
>  assertThat(mock.finalMethod()).isNotEqualTo(concrete.finalMethod());
> ```
>
> In subsequent milestones, the team will bring a programmatic way of using this feature. We will identify and provide support for all unmockable scenarios. Stay tuned and please let us know what you think of this feature!

Comment: I still get an error: **Cannot mock/spy class android.content.ComponentName
Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
- final class**

Comment: Make sure you put the `org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` file in the correct folder.

Comment: I also am getting the error even after following the above mentioned: Mockito cannot mock/spy because : - final class

Comment: User `org.mockito:mockito-core` instead `org.mockito:mockito-android` to fix the error @rcde0

Comment: @vCillusion this answer isn't related to PowerMock in any way.

Comment: I followed these instructions but I still couldn't make this work, did anyone have to do anything else?

Comment: Maker sure you have mockito version 2.X.X

Comment: I am using it with Scala, it works fine when I run test cases for my individual module but when whole application tests run in the pipeline then it fails saying "Mockito can not spy/mock".  Any Hint?

Comment: NB this mocks final methods and classes but not *static* methods, as of yet.

Comment: If you are on Windows OS, make sure you create the file without `.txt` extension.

Comment: Make sure that `mock-maker-inline` is a SINGLE LINE in `src/test/resources/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker`.

Comment: Very interesting! It did really go around the Mockito final class restriction.

Comment: This didn't work for me then a few minutes later "magically started working" maybe a `maven clean` helps?

Comment: It did work for me, I did one more step forward, i.e. cleaned the project and run the test case after that.

Comment: Mine also didn't work until I found org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker I created from Eclipse(Mac) got an extra space at the end.  Everything is woking after rename that file to the correct one.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this programmatically now?

Comment: @MarcoDufal you can add `testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:X.X.X'` instead of creating the file manually

Comment: I added this file mistakenly in Res folder instead Resouces folder. Now it's working fine.

Comment: I just get `Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)` checked the folder structure, it is single line, no spelling problem, clean and rebuild.
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.13.0"

Comment: I found the solution for above problem. Need to use the kotlin version for Android:     androidTestImplementation "org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:$mockitoKotlinVersion"
and make sure using import import org.mockito.kotlin.*

Comment: I needed both:
`testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:4.2.0'` and 
`testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:4.2.0'`

Comment: After 4 hours of searching, I found the solution in another application on Github. But in the end, this works like a charm.  Add a single file with single line to test folder like image boom, solved. 
[link](https://ibb.co/LgVq5HD)

Answer (score 93):

add this in your build file:

- if using [gradle](https://gradle.org/): `build.gradle`

```
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.13.0'
```

- if using [maven](https://maven.apache.org/): `pom.xml`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

this is a configuration to make mockito work with final classes

If you faced the `Could not initialize inline Byte Buddy mock maker. (This mock maker is not supported on Android.)`
Add the **Byte Buddy** dependency to your `build.gradle` file:

```
testImplementation 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:1.10.19'
```

src: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy

Comment: Should probably use "testImplementation" now instead of "testCompile". Gradle doesn't like "testCompile" anymore.

Comment: great comment, thanks! edited to testImplementation.
original comment: testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.13.0'

Comment: This results in error when running on Linux / OpenJDK 1.8: `org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoInitializationException: 
Could not initialize inline Byte Buddy mock maker. (This mock maker is not supported on Android.)`

Comment: Works fine when switched to Oracle JDK 1.8

Comment: This answer needs more votes! Definitely the best way to go now.

Comment: Your hint for adding Byte Buddy manually probably saved me a few hours. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 43):

You cannot mock a final class with Mockito, as you can't do it by yourself.

What I do, is to create a non-final class to wrap the final class and use as delegate. An example of this is [`TwitterFactory`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/TwitterFactory.html) class, and this is my mockable class:

```
public class TwitterFactory {

    private final twitter4j.TwitterFactory factory;

    public TwitterFactory() {
        factory = new twitter4j.TwitterFactory();
    }

    public Twitter getInstance(User user) {
        return factory.getInstance(accessToken(user));
    }

    private AccessToken accessToken(User user) {
        return new AccessToken(user.getAccessToken(), user.getAccessTokenSecret());
    }

    public Twitter getInstance() {
        return factory.getInstance();
    }
}
```

The disadvantage is that there is a lot of boilerplate code; the advantage is that you can add some methods that may relate to your application business (like the getInstance that is taking a user instead of an accessToken, in the above case).

In your case I would create a non-final `RainOnTrees` class that delegate to the final class. Or, if you can make it non-final, it would be better.

Comment: +1. If desired, you can use something like Lombok's `@Delegate` to handle a lot of the boilerplate.

Comment: @luigi can you add code snippet for Junit as an Example. I tried to create Wrapper for my final class, but couldn't fiugre out, how to test it.

Answer (score 34):

In Mockito 3 and more I have the same problem and fixed it as from this link

[Mock Final Classes and Methods with Mockito](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-final#configure-mocktio)
as follow

> Before Mockito can be used for mocking final classes and methods, it needs to be > configured.
>
> We need to add a text file to the project's src/test/resources/mockito-extensions directory named org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker and add a single line of text:
>
> ```
> mock-maker-inline
> ```
>
> Mockito checks the extensions directory for configuration files when it is loaded. This file enables the mocking of final methods and classes.

Comment: Any idea how to make it work for PowerMock

Comment: This is the correct answer, you don't need any additional dependencies aside from org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin

Answer (score 24):

Use Powermock. This link shows, how to do it: https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockFinal

Comment: I think PowerMock is like one of those pieces of medicine that should only go out on "prescription" base. In the sense of: one should make it very clear that PowerMock has **a lot** of problems; and that using it is like the ultimate last resort; and should be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: why do you say that?

Comment: I was using `Powermock` for mocking final classes and static methods to increase my coverage that was officially checked on `Sonarqube`. Coverage was 0% since SonarQube , for what ever reason does not recognize classes that use Powermock anywhere inside it. I took me and my team quite some time to realize it from some thread online. So that is just one of the reasons to be careful with Powermock and probably don't use it.

Comment: Now you can get done everything using the Mockito and no need to use the Power mock to the dependency.

Answer (score 20):

Just to follow up. Please add this line to your gradle file:

```
testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-inline', version: '2.8.9'
```

I have tried various version of mockito-core and mockito-all. Neither of them work.

Comment: To add to this, one thing i observed was that if you are using Powermock along with mockito; then adding the mockmaker plugin file in 'src/test/resources/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker' wouldn't be useful in mocking final classes. Instead, adding a dependency like mentioned by Michael_Zhang above would solve the issue of mocking final classes. 

Also, make sure you are using Mockito 2 instead of Mockito1

Answer (score 13):

I guess you made it `final` because you want to prevent other classes from extending `RainOnTrees`. As [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) suggests (item 15), there's another way to keep a class close for extension without making it `final`:

1. Remove the `final` keyword;
2. Make its constructor `private`. No class will be able to extend it because it won't be able to call the `super` constructor;
3. Create a static factory method to instantiate your class.

   ```
   // No more final keyword here.
   public class RainOnTrees {

       public static RainOnTrees newInstance() {
           return new RainOnTrees();
       }


       private RainOnTrees() {
           // Private constructor.
       }

       public void startRain() {

           // some code here
       }
   }
   ```

By using this strategy, you'll be able to use Mockito and keep your class closed for extension with little boilerplate code.

Comment: this does not work for final methods which with mockito 2 can also be mocked.

Comment: @ŁukaszRzeszotarski, the answerer (Flavio) says you don't have to mark a method final. The alternative is to make the constructor private making the extension impossible

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem. Since the class I was trying to mock was a simple class, I simply created an instance of it and returned that.

Comment: Absolutely, why mock a simple class? Mocking is for 'expensive' interactions: other services, engines, data classes etc.

Comment: If you create an instance of that, you cannot apply the Mockito.verify methods on it afterwards. The main use of mocks is to be able to test some of its methods.

Answer (score 7):

Actually there is one way, which I use for spying. It would work for you only if two preconditions are satisfied:

1. You use some kind of DI to inject an instance of final class
2. Final class implements an interface

Please recall Item 16 from [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321356683). You may create a wrapper (not final) and forward all call to the instance of final class:

```
public final class RainOnTrees implement IRainOnTrees {
    @Override public void startRain() { // some code here }
}

public class RainOnTreesWrapper implement IRainOnTrees {
    private IRainOnTrees delegate;
    public RainOnTreesWrapper(IRainOnTrees delegate) {this.delegate = delegate;}
    @Override public void startRain() { delegate.startRain(); }
}
```

Now not only can you mock your final class but also spy on it:

```
public class Seasons{
    RainOnTrees rain;
    public Seasons(IRainOnTrees rain) { this.rain = rain; };
    public void findSeasonAndRain(){
        rain.startRain();
   }
}

IRainOnTrees rain = spy(new RainOnTreesWrapper(new RainOnTrees()) // or mock(IRainOnTrees.class)
doNothing().when(rain).startRain();
new Seasons(rain).findSeasonAndRain();
```

Answer (score 6):

Another workaround, which may apply in some cases, is to create an interface that is implemented by that final class, change the code to use the interface instead of the concrete class and then mock the interface. This lets you separate the contract (interface) from the implementation (final class). Of course, if what you want is really to bind to the final class, this will not apply.

Answer (score 6):

Time saver for people who are facing the same issue (Mockito + Final Class) on Android + Kotlin. As in Kotlin classes are final by default. I found a solution in one of Google Android samples with Architecture component. Solution picked from here : https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample

Create following annotations :

```
/**
 * This annotation allows us to open some classes for mocking purposes while they are final in
 * release builds.
 */
@Target(AnnotationTarget.ANNOTATION_CLASS)
annotation class OpenClass

/**
 * Annotate a class with [OpenForTesting] if you want it to be extendable in debug builds.
 */
@OpenClass
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
annotation class OpenForTesting
```

Modify your gradle file. Take example from here : https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-allopen'

allOpen {
    // allows mocking for classes w/o directly opening them for release builds
    annotation 'com.android.example.github.testing.OpenClass'
}
```

Now you can annotate any class to make it open for testing :

```
@OpenForTesting
class RepoRepository
```

Comment: This works well at app level build.gradle but what can we do to get this on library level?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Usually, use facade pattern to connect to libs. And mock these facade classes to test the app. In this way we don't need to mock any lib classes.

Comment: I don't see any test-specific options. The procedure is fully matches with the [official instruction](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#using-in-gradle). So class will be open in production as well.

Answer (score 5):

Give this a try:

```
Mockito.mock(SomeMockableType.class,AdditionalAnswers.delegatesTo(someInstanceThatIsNotMockableOrSpyable));
```

It worked for me. "SomeMockableType.class" is the parent class of what you want to mock or spy, and someInstanceThatIsNotMockableOrSpyable is the actual class that you want to mock or spy.

For more details have a look [here](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=145)

Comment: It should be noticed that delegates is very different from native spy mocking.

In a native mockito spy, "this" in the instance reference to the spy itself (because is use subclass)

However, in delegate, "this" will be the real object someInstanceThatIsNotMockableOrSpyable. Not the spy. 

Thus, there is no way to doReturn/verify for self-calling functions.

Comment: can you put up a example?

Answer (score 4):

This can be done if you are using Mockito2, with the new incubating feature which supports mocking of final classes & methods.

**Key points to note:**
1.  Create a simple file with the name “org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker” and place it in a folder named “mockito-extensions”. This folder should be made available on the classpath.
2.  The content of the file created above should be a single line as given below:
**mock-maker-inline**

The above two steps are required in order to activate the mockito extension mechanism and use this opt-in feature.

Sample classes are as follows:-

FinalClass.java

```
public final class FinalClass {

public final String hello(){
    System.out.println("Final class says Hello!!!");
    return "0";
}
```

}

Foo.java

```
public class Foo {

public String executeFinal(FinalClass finalClass){
    return finalClass.hello();
}
```

}

FooTest.java

```
public class FooTest {

@Test
public void testFinalClass(){
    // Instantiate the class under test.
    Foo foo = new Foo();

    // Instantiate the external dependency
    FinalClass realFinalClass = new FinalClass();

    // Create mock object for the final class. 
    FinalClass mockedFinalClass = mock(FinalClass.class);

    // Provide stub for mocked object.
    when(mockedFinalClass.hello()).thenReturn("1");

    // assert
    assertEquals("0", foo.executeFinal(realFinalClass));
    assertEquals("1", foo.executeFinal(mockedFinalClass));

}
```

}

Hope it helps.

Complete article present here [mocking-the-unmockable](https://dzone.com/articles/mocking-the-unmockable-the-mockito2-way).

Comment: You should include the answer here and not link to an external site. If the procedure is long you could include an overview.

Comment: please ensure below annotations are used when mocking
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({AFinalClass.class})

Comment: @vCillusion - The example I have shown just uses the Mockito2 API.Using the opt-in feature of Mockito2, one can mock the final classes directly without the need to use Powermock.

Answer (score 3):

Yes same problem here, we cannot mock a final class with Mockito. To be accurate, Mockito cannot mock/spy following:

- final classes
- anonymous classes
- primitive types

But using a wrapper class seems to me a big price to pay, so get PowerMockito instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to use Mockito in an instrumented test in Android (i. e. running in an Android device), you cannot use `mockito-inline`. There is a special `mockito-android` version which doesn't solve the "final class" problem either. The only solution which seems to work is the [Dexmaker library](https://github.com/linkedin/dexmaker). The only limitation is that it works only in Android P (Android 9, API 28) and higher. It can be imported as follows:

```
androidTestImplementation "com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito-inline:2.28.1"
```

Beware that there is also a "dexmaker-mockito" version which doesn't work for final classes either. Make sure you import "dexmaker-mockito-inline".

Edit: Eventually I just migrated everything to Mockk to get rid of all the problems.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need think more in principle. Instead you final class use his interface and mock interface  instead.

For this:

```
 public class RainOnTrees{

   fun startRain():Observable<Boolean>{

        // some code here
   }
}
```

add

```
interface iRainOnTrees{
  public void startRain():Observable<Boolean>
}
```

and mock you interface:

```
 @Before
    fun setUp() {
        rainService= Mockito.mock(iRainOnTrees::class.java)

        `when`(rainService.startRain()).thenReturn(
            just(true).delay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        )

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

#### As of Mockito 5.x, you can mock final classes and methods out-of-the-box like any non-finals.

No additional dependencies (such as `mockito-inline`) required anymore.

Here is an article outlining the most important changes and improvements in version 5: https://www.infoq.com/news/2023/01/mockito-5/

Sidenote: i was actually rather confused after reading this [Baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-final) which is from June 2023 and simply omits the most important detail, namely that you need Mockito 5 for this.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at [JMockit](http://jmockit.github.io/). It has extensive documentation with a lot of examples. Here you have an example solution of your problem (to simplify I've added constructor to `Seasons` to inject mocked `RainOnTrees` instance):

```
package jmockitexample;

import mockit.Mocked;
import mockit.Verifications;
import mockit.integration.junit4.JMockit;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class SeasonsTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldStartRain(@Mocked final RainOnTrees rain) {
        Seasons seasons = new Seasons(rain);

        seasons.findSeasonAndRain();

        new Verifications() {{
            rain.startRain();
        }};
    }

    public final class RainOnTrees {
        public void startRain() {
            // some code here
        }

    }

    public class Seasons {

        private final RainOnTrees rain;

        public Seasons(RainOnTrees rain) {
            this.rain = rain;
        }

        public void findSeasonAndRain() {
            rain.startRain();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solutions provided by RC and Luigi R. Viggiano together is possibly the best idea.

Although Mockito **cannot**, by design, mock final classes, the delegation approach **is possible**. This has its advantages:

1. You are not forced to change your class to non-final if that is what your API intends in the first place (final classes have their [benefits](https://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA87&lpg=PA87&dq=bloch%20effective%20java%20item%2017&source=bl&ots=yZGoOfo2VY&sig=ke5qo7Dw9IkMLKq0dyTIfbTuzyk&hl=en&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwj_-Kn_n83JAhWJGY4KHc-HB2UQ6AEIMjAD#v=onepage&q=bloch%20effective%20java%20item%2017&f=false)).
2. You are testing the possibility of a [decoration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) around your API.

In your test case, you deliberately forward the calls to the system under test. Hence, by design, your decoration does *not* do anything.

Hence you test can also demonstrate that the user can only decorate the API instead of extending it.

On a more subjective note:
I prefer keeping the frameworks to a minimum, which is why JUnit and Mockito are usually sufficient for me. In fact, restricting this way sometimes forces me to refactor for good as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you trying to run unit-test under the **test** folder, the top solution is fine. Just follow it adding an extension.

But if you want to run it with **android related** class like context or activity which is under **androidtest** folder, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50457516/3531558) is for you.

Answer (score 1):

Add these dependencies for run mockito successfully :

**testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.24.5'

testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.24.5"**

Answer (score 1):

Mocking final classes is **not supported** for **mockito-android** as per this GitHub issue. You should use Mockk instead for this.

For both unit test and ui test, you can use Mockk with no problem.

Comment: which issue? can you provide a link?

Answer (score 1):

I am writing the steps I followed after various unsuccessful attempts to mock final/private classes and their methods in Java 11, which finally worked for me.

1. Create a file named *org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker* inside
   your *test/resources/mockito-extensions* folder. Please create
   *mockito-extensions* folder if not present already.
2. Add a single line *mock-maker-inline* as the content of the above *org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker* file
3. Add

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.management.*", "jdk.internal.reflect.*", "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.*", "javax.xml.*", "org.xml.*", "org.w3c.*"})
@PrepareForTest(Utility.class)
```

annotations at the class level.

Setup process in the test class

```
  @Before
  public void setup () {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    Mockito.mockStatic(ClassToBeMocked.class); 
  }
```

4. Use *Mockito.when(..).thenReturn(..)* for assertions
5. In case of multiple test cases, add the below code

```
  @After
  public void after() {
        Mockito.framework().clearInlineMocks();
  }
```

The mockito version which I am using: 3.9.0
Java version: 11

Comment: Don't use PowerMockito, there are better and more maintained options that don't have compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, this won't work out of the box with Mockito. I would suggest using reflection to set the specific fields on the object that is being used by the code under test. If you find yourself doing this a lot, you can wrap this functionality in a library.

As an aside, if you are the one marking classes final, stop doing that. I ran across this question because I am working with an API where everything was marked final to prevent my legitimate need for extension (mocking), and I wish that the developer had not assumed that I would never need to extend the class.

Comment: Public API classes should be open for extension. Wholly agree. However, in a private code-base, `final` should be the default.

Answer (score 0):

For us, it was because we excluded mockito-inline from koin-test.  One gradle module actually needed this and for reason only failed on release builds (debug builds in the IDE worked) :-P

Answer (score 0):

For final class add below to mock and call static or non static.

1- add this in class level
   @SuppressStatucInitializationFor(value ={class name with package})
2- PowerMockito.mockStatic(classname.class) will mock class
3- then use your when statement to return mock object when calling method of this class.

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome this message:

> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
> Cannot mock/spy class org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter
> Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
>
> - final or anonymous class

from this: `log = spy(log);`

By using this instead:

`log = mock(Logger.class);`

Then it works.

I guess that "default" logger adapter is an instance of a final class so I couldn't "spy" it, but I could mock the whole thing.  Go figure...

This may mean that you could substitute it for some other "non final" instance if you have that handy, as well.  Or a simplified version, etc. FWIW...

Answer (score -5):

Didn't try final, but for private, using reflection remove the modifier worked ! have checked further, it doesn't work for final.

Comment: this is not answering the question asked