# How to mock the CloaseableHttpResponse from apache http client 5.x?

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, apache-httpclient-5.x

I'm using apache http client version 5.x, and I'm struglling to implement mocked unit tests for the `CloseableHttpResponse execute(ClassicHttpRequest request)` method from `CloseableHttpClient` class, since the response type is final and there is no public way to instantiate it.

The following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846526/how-can-i-create-a-closeablehttpresponse-object-to-help-testing) provided some ways to do it, but the discussion seems to be around the older versions of the apache http client, and although I was able to enable mockito to mock final types, it seems to be risky, as documentation itself warns that this is a [completely different mocking mechanism that requires more feedback from the community](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.11.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#39).

Is there an easier/proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is janky as all get out, but this seems to work

```
        ClassicHttpResponse classicResponse = Mockito.mock(ClassicHttpResponse.class);
        Mockito.when(classicResponse.getCode()).thenReturn(200);
        Method m = CloseableHttpResponse.class.getDeclaredMethod("adapt", ClassicHttpResponse.class);
        m.setAccessible(true);
        CloseableHttpResponse response = (CloseableHttpResponse) m.invoke(null, classicResponse);
```

Answer (score 0):

One should never need to mock `CloseableHttpResponse`. It is provided for compatibility with HC 4.x and ought not be used by any new code.

One should be using methods of `HttpClient` interface that take a lamdba expression or `#executeOpen` method that returns `ClassicHttpResponse` interface.