# Cannot Mockito spy class in Spock test?

Tags: java, groovy, mocking, mockito, spock

I'm trying to spy a Java class in a Spock test. I've not had a problem with Mockito in Spock/Groovy before.

When I try to do the following:

```
def service = spy(Service.class)
```

I get the following error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot mock/spy class java.lang.Class
Mockito cannot mock/spy following:
  - final classes
  - anonymous classes
  - primitive types
```

When I do `mock(Service.class)` though, it works fine.

I have confirmed that the class is not final, anonymous, or primitive.

Any ideas? I have a random generator in the class (ak) so I need to spy not mock.

Thank you

Comment: In case you are not aware, Spock comes with out-of-the-box support for spying.

Comment: Why would anybody use Mockito with Spock? Just use builtin method `Spy(Service)` and done.

Comment: @topr Partly because I'm familiar with Mockito, and I find its syntax clear and concise enough not to stand out in Groovy. But mainly because the homegrown options I've found in Groovy using closures and expandos look difficult to read, and would probably not go over well with my team. I didn't realize there was a Spy construction (is there a Mock?) - I'll take a look, thanks.

Comment: Teamm knowing a given till is surely a good argument. However why you go for Spock at then? :) Yes, there is Mock(), Stub() and respectively GroovySpy(), GroovyMock() and GroovyStub() with extended features mostly related to dynamic methods added in runtime. I like Spock for multiple things, one is that it's self-contained. One needs NO additional libs to do proper tests.

Comment: given lib* (time for edition expired)

Comment: Please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/39128168/2381172

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mockito doesn't spy on Classes (or Mocks), it spies on (regular) Objects. Thus, instead of

```
def service = spy(Service.class)
```

you have to write

```
def service = spy(new Service())
```

(or whichever constructor is appropriate for your scenario).

Answer (score 0):

Just an extra to Ray's answer, you can also spy on already created instances. The only thing is that all methods you called before `spy()` was called, cannot be verified. Like:

```java
ClassToSpy spiedInstance;

@Before
public void before () {
    spiedInstance = new ClassToSpy();
}

@Test
public void testWillFail() {
    spiedInstance.method();
    spiedInstance = spy(spiedInstance);

    verify(spiedInstance).method();
}

@Test
public void testWillPass() {
    spiedInstance = spy(spiedInstance);
    spiedInstance.method();

    verify(spiedInstance).method();
}
```

The error you would get from `testWillFail` would be similar to:

```java
Wanted but not invoked:
classToSpy.method();
-> at your.package.testWillFail(TestClass.java:line)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Due to the fact that, after spied, you did not call this method.