# How to mock DataSourceTransactionManager ?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have the following code which I would like to mock. I'm basically interested in mocking the DataSourceTransactionManager.

```
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("nesTransactionManager")
    DataSourceTransactionManager mDataSourceTransactionManager;

   ...............................

    DefaultTransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
            def.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
       TransactionStatus status = mDataSourceTransactionManager.getTransaction(def);

       try {
          <-doing some DB operations here>
          mDataSourceTransactionManager.commit(status);
       } catch (Exception e) {
          mDataSourceTransactionManager.rollback(status);
       }
.............
```

So far I've tried this:

```
    @Mock
    private DataSourceTransactionManager mDataSourceTransactionManager;

   @Before
    public void runBeforeEachTest() {
        when(mDataSourceTransactionManager.getTransaction(any(DefaultTransactionDefinition.class))).thenReturn(null);
        doNothing().when(mDataSourceTransactionManager).commit(any(TransactionStatus.class));
        doNothing().when(mDataSourceTransactionManager).rollback(any(TransactionStatus.class));
}
```

And this:

```
    @Mock
    private DataSourceTransactionManager mDataSourceTransactionManager;

   @Before
    public void runBeforeEachTest() {
DefaultTransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
        def.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);

        when(mDataSourceTransactionManager.getTransaction(eq(def))).thenReturn(null);
        doNothing().when(mDataSourceTransactionManager).commit(any(TransactionStatus.class));
        doNothing().when(mDataSourceTransactionManager).rollback(any(TransactionStatus.class));
```

But I've always got this error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
0 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
-> at com.nuance.entrd.mc.nes.jobs.JobPollerTest.runBeforeEachTest(JobPollerTest.java:43)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.

    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:337)
```

Error which doesn't make any sense in this context. Any idea on how can I address this ?

Thanks

Comment: Note that the error is generated at the when line

Comment: So you're creating a mock in your test.  Your stubbing does nothing.  But more importantly, how are you injecting that mock into the class that you're testing?

Comment: Well, i have a setter for that : jobPoller.setDataSourceTransactionManager(mDataSourceTransactionManager);  But again, The error is being thrown before getting to that setter.

Comment: Can you show us your getTransaction() method?

Comment: It's the spring framework DataSourceTransactionManager.getTransaction() http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/support/AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.html#getTransaction(org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition)

Comment: According to that documentation, that method is final.  You can't stub a final method in Mockito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've solved my problem was to use PowerMokito :

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({DataSourceTransactionManager.class})
public class JobPollerTest {
.....................
 private DataSourceTransactionManager mDataSourceTransactionManager;
......................

    mDataSourceTransactionManager = PowerMockito.mock(DataSourceTransactionManager.class);

     DefaultTransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
            def.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);

            Mockito.when(mDataSourceTransactionManager.getTransaction(def)).thenReturn(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to add the following line above your test class name.

```
@PrepareForTest(DataSourceTransactionManager.class)
public class yourTestName{
```

The second step is to add the mock as follows:

```
@Mock
DataSourceTransactionManager dstManager;
```

Third step:

```
@Mock
TransactionStatus tranStatus;
```

Fourth step in the `@test` method please initialize as follows:

```
TransactionDefinition transDef=new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
Mockito.when(dstManager.getTransaction(transDef)).thenReturn(tranStatus);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Mockito with **final** classes and methods

There are several things you can do to resolve your issue, and **PowerMock** is one of them:

- [How to use mockito with final classes and methods - Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-final)
- [Another Stackoverflow thread well describing the issue and its resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292863/how-to-mock-a-final-class-with-mockito)