# Why can't we mock a final class?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, final

I am new to Java and haven't done much of unit testing in general.
Can someone tell me why `final` classes cannot be mocked?

Answer (score 5):

Most common mocking framework in the java world cannot mock `final` classes/methods because they are typically based on creating proxies. Creating proxies for `final` classes is not possible as we cannot subclass (`extends`) a `final` class.

However, there are some workarounds and solutions, many of which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292863/how-to-mock-a-final-class-with-mockito).

Answer (score 2):

JMockit is able to mock final classes, methods, static and private fields, because it is primarily based on java.lang.instrument package classes and on proxy objects creation.