# How to mock a Kotlin singleton object?

Tags: mocking, mockito, kotlin, powermock, powermockito

Given a Kotlin singleton object and a fun that call it's method

```
object SomeObject {
   fun someFun() {}
}

fun callerFun() {
   SomeObject.someFun()
}
```

Is there a way to mock call to `SomeObject.someFun()`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just make your object implement an interface, then you can mock your object with any mocking library. Here is an example using Junit + Mockito + [Mockito-Kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin):

```
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.mock
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.whenever
import org.junit.Assert.assertEquals
import org.junit.Test

object SomeObject : SomeInterface {
    override fun someFun():String {
        return ""
    }
}

interface SomeInterface {
    fun someFun():String
}

class SampleTest {

    @Test
    fun test_with_mock() {
        val mock = mock<SomeInterface>()

        whenever(mock.someFun()).thenReturn("42")

        val answer = mock.someFun()

        assertEquals("42", answer)
    }
}
```

Or in case you want to mock `SomeObject` inside `callerFun`:

```
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.mock
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.whenever
import org.junit.Assert.assertEquals
import org.junit.Test

object SomeObject : SomeInterface {
    override fun someFun():String {
        return ""
    }
}

class Caller(val someInterface: SomeInterface) {
    fun callerFun():String {
        return "Test ${someInterface.someFun()}"
    }
}

// Example of use
val test = Caller(SomeObject).callerFun()

interface SomeInterface {
    fun someFun():String
}

class SampleTest {

    @Test
    fun test_with_mock() {
        val mock = mock<SomeInterface>()
        val caller = Caller(mock)

        whenever(mock.someFun()).thenReturn("42")

        val answer = caller.callerFun()

        assertEquals("Test 42", answer)
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like an anti-pattern... One shouldn't create extra classes/interfaces in main code just for the purpose of testing!

Comment: Not extra classes, just interfaces. And you should do it because this is best practice for testing on JVM.

Comment: Usually mock.someFun() is called in the class that is being tested, not in test class. Since you can't mock the object in the actual it won't work.

Answer (score 79):

There's a very nice mocking library for Kotlin - [Mockk](http://mockk.io/), which allows you to mock objects, the exact same way you're desiring.

As of its documentation:

---

> Objects can be transformed to mocks following way:

```
object MockObj {
  fun add(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
}

mockkObject(MockObj) // aplies mocking to an Object

assertEquals(3, MockObj.add(1, 2))

every { MockObj.add(1, 2) } returns 55

assertEquals(55, MockObj.add(1, 2))
```

> To revert back use unmockkAll or unmockkObject:

```
@Before
fun beforeTests() {
    mockkObject(MockObj)
    every { MockObj.add(1,2) } returns 55
}

@Test
fun willUseMockBehaviour() {
    assertEquals(55, MockObj.add(1,2))
}

@After
fun afterTests() {
    unmockkAll()
    // or unmockkObject(MockObj)
}
```

> Despite Kotlin language limits you can create new instances of objects if testing logic needs that:

```
val newObjectMock = mockk<MockObj>()
```

Comment: Also so question didnt say so but in android instrumentation test this wont work with devices api lower than pie: https://mockk.io/ANDROID.html
therefore Ruslans answer is more safe to use

Answer (score 11):

Besides using [Mockk](http://mockk.io/) library, which is quite convenient, one could mock an `object` simply with Mockito and reflection. A Kotlin object is just a regular Java class with a private constructor and an `INSTANCE` static field, with reflection one can replace the value of `INSTANCE` with a mocked object. After the test the original should be restored so that the change won't affect other tests

Using Mockito Kotlin (one needs to add an extension configuration as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40018295/1527232) to mock final classes):

```
testCompile "com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.5.0"
```

A first fun could replace the value of the static `INSTANCE` field in the `object` class and return the previous value

```
fun <T> replaceObjectInstance(clazz: Class<T>, newInstance: T): T {

    if (!clazz.declaredFields.any {
                it.name == "INSTANCE" && it.type == clazz && Modifier.isStatic(it.modifiers)
            }) {
        throw InstantiationException("clazz ${clazz.canonicalName} does not have a static  " +
                "INSTANCE field, is it really a Kotlin \"object\"?")
    }

    val instanceField = clazz.getDeclaredField("INSTANCE")
    val modifiersField = Field::class.java.getDeclaredField("modifiers")
    modifiersField.isAccessible = true
    modifiersField.setInt(instanceField, instanceField.modifiers and Modifier.FINAL.inv())

    instanceField.isAccessible = true
    val originalInstance = instanceField.get(null) as T
    instanceField.set(null, newInstance)
    return originalInstance
}
```

Then you could have a fun that will create a mock instance of the `object` and replace the original value with the mocked one, returning the original so that it can be reset later

```
fun <T> mockObject(clazz: Class<T>): T {
    val constructor = clazz.declaredConstructors.find { it.parameterCount == 0 }
            ?: throw InstantiationException("class ${clazz.canonicalName} has no empty constructor, " +
                    "is it really a Kotlin \"object\"?")

    constructor.isAccessible = true

    val mockedInstance = spy(constructor.newInstance() as T)

    return replaceObjectInstance(clazz, mockedInstance)
}
```

Add some Kotlin sugar

```
class MockedScope<T : Any>(private val clazz: Class<T>) {

    fun test(block: () -> Unit) {
        val originalInstance = mockObject(clazz)
        block.invoke()
        replaceObjectInstance(clazz, originalInstance)
    }
}

fun <T : Any> withMockObject(clazz: Class<T>) = MockedScope(clazz)
```

And finally, given an `object`

```
object Foo {
    fun bar(arg: String) = 0
}
```

You could test it this way

```
withMockObject(Foo.javaClass).test {
    doAnswer { 1 }.whenever(Foo).bar(any())

    Assert.assertEquals(1, Foo.bar(""))
}

Assert.assertEquals(0, Foo.bar(""))
```

Comment: Basically, you are relying on Kotlin implementation details: anytime Kotile designers decide to change the implementation of `object` classes then you should update all your tests.

Comment: Well, you wouldn't need to change _all your tests_, only the mocking function. But most importantly, if the implementation of `object` changed, you would need to recompile older code. If you compile `Foo.bar()` today, the compiled outcome would use an `INSTANCE` field as well.

Comment: That also works for me! Using mockito-kotlin `2.0.0-RC2`, haven't checked if version 2 provides something more straight forward though.

Comment: This will break after Java 11 as they have add `Field` deny list for reflection so `Field::class.java.getDeclaredField("modifiers")` will crash with `java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: modifiers`

Answer (score 10):

You can mock Object without any extra library, by using class *delegates*.

Here is my proposal

```
val someObjectDelegate : SomeInterface? = null

object SomeObject: by someObjectDelegate ?: SomeObjectImpl

object SomeObjectImpl : SomeInterface {

    fun someFun() {
        println("SomeObjectImpl someFun called")
    }
}

interface SomeInterface {
    fun someFun()
}
```

In your tests you can set delegate object that will change behaviour, otherwise it will use it's real implementation.

```
@Beofre
fun setUp() {
  someObjectDelegate = object : SomeInterface {
      fun someFun() {
          println("Mocked function")
      }
  }
  // Will call method from your delegate
  SomeObject.someFun()
}
```

*Of course names above are bad, but for the sake of an example it shows the purpose.*

After SomeObject is initialised delegate will handle all the functions.
More you can find in official [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html)

Comment: Theoretically, when you do this you should also test that your delegates work correctly, and writing a test for that will also require a delegate and so on... Using a mocked alternative, we trust that t he mock library is tested itself, and we don't need to add extra boilerplate and extra lines for this concept

Comment: For sure using a mock lib is the better approach but not possible for android instrumentationtest lower than android pie. Therefor this solution looks pretty good!

Comment: this is pretty neat without using any library

Answer (score 3):

For Mockito, we can use `Mockito.mockStatic()`

```kotlin
Mockito.mockStatic(SomeObject::class.java).use { mocked ->
    mocked.`when`<SomeType> { SomeObject.callAFunction() }
        .thenReturn(someMockedValue)
    
    // Your test goes here
}
```

Ouside `use`'s scope, the value of `callAFunction()` is reset

Answer (score 1):

Short of manipulating byte code the answer is no, unless you are willing and able to change the code. The most straightforward way (and the way I would recommend) to mock `callerFun`'s call to `SomeObject.someFun()` is to provide some way to slip it a mock object.

e.g.

```
object SomeObject {
    fun someFun() {}
}

fun callerFun() {
    _callerFun { SomeObject.someFun() }
}

internal inline fun _callerFun(caller: () -> Unit) {
    caller()
}
```

The idea here is to change something you're willing to change. If you're certain you want a singleton and a top-level function that acts on that singleton then one way, as demonstrated above, to make the top-level function testable without changing its public signature is to move its implementation to an `internal` function that allows slipping a mock.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you can use mockkObject

```
object FeatureFlags {
      val featureEnabled = true
    }
    
    mockkObject(FeatureFlags)
    every { FeatureFlags.featureEnabled } returns false
    
    // prints false
    println(FeatureFlags.featureEnabled)
```