# Test a call in Kotlin object

Tags: unit-testing, testing, logging, kotlin

I have a Kotlin class like this one

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger
object Doer {
    val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Doer::class.java)

    fun doSomething() : Int {
        logger.warn("Doing.")
        return 123
    }
}
```

I would like to have a unit test that verifies `logger.warn` call was made with relevant message. How do I do this in Kotlin? 
One of my ideas was to use a getter for logger and stub that with Mockito, but do I need to declare such method explicitly given that Kotlin generates getters automatically? Method `getLogger()` is not visible in `Doer` class, but if I declare it explicitly it conflicts with generated one.
Are there better options to test this?

Second question is how to mock the object instance, since it is initialized by language which is out of my control?

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977320/how-to-mock-a-kotlin-singleton-object

Comment: Why do you want to test logging?

Comment: @LaksithaRanasingha Because it is essential part of app logic.