# kotlin : unit test with mock injection (mockK)

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, junit, mockk

I followed step by step instructions from many blogs for implementing a mock with MockK:

```
class SWServiceImplTest {

    @MockK
    lateinit var externalApi: ExternalApiService

    @InjectMockKs
    lateinit var SWService: SWServiceImpl

    @Before
    fun setUp() = MockKAnnotations.init(this)

    @Test
    fun SWCharacterReturnsCorrectValues() {

        every { externalApi.get<Characters>(Utils.SW_API) } returns mockCharacters()

        val result = SWService.swCharacter!!
        assertEquals("blue", result.first().color?.toLowerCase())
        assertEquals(result.size, 3)
    }

}
```

I want to inject `externalApi` into my  `SWService` service and mock the `get` method of the injected object (`externalApi`) but it seems that the mock is ignored.

logs :

```
15:09:54.497 [main] DEBUG io.mockk.impl.instantiation.AbstractMockFactory - Creating mockk for <error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/coroutines/intrinsics/IntrinsicsKt"> name=externalApi#1
15:09:56.820 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - HTTP GET https://xxx.xxx/
15:09:57.038 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Accept=[application/json, application/*+json]

org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: No HttpMessageConverter for java.lang.Object and content type ""
```

In my `SWService` file, `externalApi` is initialized in a companion object :

```
    companion object{
        val api = ExternalApiService()
    }
```

Something wrong in my implementation ?
Thanks

Comment: How you are initializing `externalApi` in `SWService` class? Could you paste that code too?

Comment: Thanks @SuryavelTR for your comment. I've updated my message : It's initialized in a companion object in my class

Comment: Deleted a comment. Missed the point about InjectMocks SWService. So. You are not able to InjectMocks into companion object. I would suggest to have `api` something alike `lateinit var` as a field or `val` in the constructor(believe this one works as well)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock a Kotlin singleton object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977320/how-to-mock-a-kotlin-singleton-object)

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin generates a inner class for `companion object {}` called `Companion`. This `Companion` class would have only getters for the fields declared (in your case `getApi()`). But the field is maintained by outer class `SWService`.

So equivalent java class for SWService would look like.

```
public final class SWService {
   private static final ExternalApiService api = new ExternalApiService();

   public static final class Companion() {
       public final ExternalApiService getApi() {
          return SWService.api;
       }
   }
}
```

Now you want to mock `api` which is `static` field. This can be done using `powermockito`.

Add this dependency,

```
testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.0-beta.5"
```

And in your test,

```
public final class SWServiceTest {

   @MockK
   lateinit var api: ExternalApiService

   var service = SWService()

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockKAnnotations.init(this)
        Whitebox.setInternalState(SWService::class.java,"api", api);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to implement with `powermock` but I'm still getting the same error... (Creating mockk for <error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError..)