# How to test add method in Kotlin object Singleton class

Tags: kotlin, junit

I'm trying to do some testing in my object kotlin class, but I can getting an error in my thenReturn method when I try to pass the object. I get a Require: Unit! Found checkout. Someone can point me how is possible to test it??

If I remove thenReturn method I get this error:

```
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, which is not supported
 3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed
```

I refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977320/how-to-mock-a-kotlin-singleton-object/37978020#37978020) but I can't get it.

```
object CheckoutRepository: CheckoutContract.Model {

    var checkout: MutableList<Checkout> = mutableListOf<Checkout>()

    override fun addProductToShoppingCart(checkoutProduct: Checkout){
        checkout.add(checkoutProduct)
    }

    override fun getProductsInShoppinCart() : List<Checkout>?{
        return checkout
    }

    override fun cleanCheckout(){
        checkout.clear()
    }
}



@Test
    fun test_with_mock() {
        val mock = mock<CheckoutContract.Model>()

        var checkout = Checkout("VOUCHER", "voucher", 35.0, 5)
        mock.addProductToShoppingCart(checkout)

        val answer = mock.getProductsInShoppinCart()
        `when`(mock.addProductToShoppingCart(checkout)).thenReturn(checkout)

        assertNotNull(checkout)
        assertEquals(checkout, answer)
    }
```

Comment: In your function addProductToShoppingCart don't have any return type

Comment: Yes, I don't need the return type in function. Then, how can I test the addProductToShoppingCart method is working?

Answer (score 0):

In your function addProductToShoppingCart don't have any return type.

if you want check Checkout class make the change in the functions then test case will pass

```
override fun addProductToShoppingCart(checkoutProduct: Checkout):Checkout{
    checkout.add(checkoutProduct)
return checkout
}
```

Comment: Yes, I don't need the return type. If I remove the thenReturn I get the error:  missing thenReturn() Check my question. That I want to do is test the addProductToShoppingCart is working