# How to use Mockito.mockStatic for mocking static methods in kotlin android

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, junit, mockito

How to use Mockito.mockStatic for mocking static methods in kotlin android ?

This is my code:

```
    class MyUtilClassTest {
       @Test
       fun testIsEnabled() {
          Mockito.mockStatic(MyUtilClass::class.java, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS)
                .use { mocked ->
                    mocked.`when`<Boolean> { MyUtilClass.isEnabled() }.thenReturn(true)
                    assertTrue(MyUtilClass.isEnabled())
                }
       }
    }
    
    object MyUtilClass {
       fun isEnabled(): Boolean = false
    }
```

I am getting this exception:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException:
> when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
> For example:
> when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);
>
> Also, this error might show up because:
>
> 1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
>    Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
>    Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
> 2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.

Comment: If your objective is to mock Kotlin objects, there's already an answer for that:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977320/how-to-mock-a-kotlin-singleton-object

Answer (score 6):

If you annotate your function `isEnabled` with `@JvmStatic`, you won't get any error. As [@Neige](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3429542/neige) pointed out, static functions in `Kotlin` are actually not static in `bytecode` by default. Therefore, we need to mark our function with `@JvmStatic` in order to generate additional static `getter/setter` methods.

```
object MyUtilClass {
   @JvmStatic
   fun isEnabled(): Boolean = false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the JVM point of view `MyUtilClass.isEnabled()` is not a static class/function.
You can use `Show Kotlin Bytecode` to understand what is behind

```
public final class MyUtilClass {
   public static final MyUtilClass INSTANCE;

   public final boolean isEnabled() {
      return false;
   }

   private MyUtilClass() {
   }

   static {
      MyUtilClass var0 = new MyUtilClass();
      INSTANCE = var0;
   }
}
```