# How to verify that an object function was invoked during a catch (within an assertThrows)

Tags: kotlin, mockito

say for example I have a function for which im trying to test out exception handling:

```
fun something() {
    try {
        doSomething(input)
    } catch (e: SomeException) {
        someObject.evalSomeException(e)
    }
}

object someObject {
    fun evalSomeException (e: SomeException) {
        throw SomeOtherException()
    }
}
```

im trying to `verify()` that `someObject.evalSomeException` was invoked once. How do I do this?

in my test, im asserting this:

```
private val mockSomeObject = mock<SomeObject>()

assertThrows<SomeOtherException>{
    something(inputThatCausesSomeException)
}

verify(mockSomeObject, times(1)).evalSomeException(SomeException())
```

Adding `verify(someObject, times(1)).evalSomeException(SomeException())` outside the assertThrows does not work (there were zero interactions with this mock).
Adding it inside the assertThrows, the verify line does not get evaluated.
Even tried `spy` but I cannot seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Mockito uses equality to match arguments. Exceptions don't implement any equality, so your line:

```
verify(someObject, times(1)).evalSomeException(SomeException())
```

is expecting that `evalSomeException` will be called with a *different* exception to the one it's actually called with.

Use [Mockito's argument matchers](https://site.mockito.org/javadoc/current/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html) in place of the argument, for instance:

```
verify(someObject, times(1)).evalSomeException(any())
```

If you're getting no interactions with the mock whatsoever, check that you're verifying the mock *after* you exercise your class under test, and that `someObject` is actually the mock object when testing; that is, you're injecting it into the class correctly.

Comment: this also results in `Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock`

Comment: @user2883071 How are you mocking `SomeObject`? If possible, it would be best to add a proper [mre] to your question.

Comment: updated the question with the mock

Comment: @user2883071 The `mockSomeObject` instance is not the same instance that `evalSomeException` is being invoked on. Perhaps something here will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977320/how-to-mock-a-kotlin-singleton-object

Comment: I've also updated my answer with a couple of checks for no interactions at all.