# Mocking java.lang.reflect.Method using Mockito

Tags: java, class, mockito, final

I need to mock `java.lang.reflect.Method` for my test (I have dynamic things). We have written all the test cases using Junit spring & mockito. But I am facing issue while writing Junit for my Aspects.
Also we have written custom annotation. Please help me on this

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:spring/services-test.xml")
@ImportAutoConfiguration(RefreshAutoConfiguration.class)
public abstract class AbsServicesTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {
    
    static{
        System.setProperty("LOCAL");
    }
}


public class TaxValidatorAspectTest extends AbsServicesTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private ResourcesUtils resourcesUtil;
    
    @Mock
    private JoinPoint joinPoint;
    
    @Mock
    private MethodSignature methodSignature;
    
    @Mock
    private Method method;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(new TaxValidatorAspectTest());
        Mockito.when(joinPoint.getSignature()).thenReturn(methodSignature);
        Mockito.when(methodSignature.getMethod()).thenReturn(method);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testBeforeMethod() throws IOException{
        TaxValidatorAspect taxonomyValidationAspect = new TaxValidatorAspect();
        final Object[] arguments = new Object[4];
        arguments[0] = requiredParam1;
        arguments[1] = requiredParam2;
        arguments[2] = requiredParam3;
        Mockito.when(joinPoint.getArgs()).thenReturn(arguments);
        taxonomyValidationAspect.before(joinPoint);
    }
}
```

I am getting error like below

```
    org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
    Cannot mock/spy class java.lang.reflect.Method
    Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
     - final or anonymous class
        at com.taxvalidation.TaxValidatorAspectTest.setUp(TaxValidatorAspectTest.java:55)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mock a final class with mockito](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292863/how-to-mock-a-final-class-with-mockito)

Comment: Read the exception message and google that. Don't get me wrong, but this sounds a little bit like you are overburdening yourself. The idea to use mockito to override **reflection** sounds pretty much *advanced* to me. Meaning: when you are up to such things, then a clear exception message like "cant mock final" should be really good enough to get you going ...

Comment: Not only are you trying to mock final classes and methods belonging to the JVM, but you're also initializing mocks in a separate test from the one JUnit is running (`initMocks(new TaxValidatorAspectTest())`). Even after those are fixed, using Mockito to mock reflection sounds like a bad idea to me. In your shoes I'd just create a small test class, apply the Aspect to it, and see if it gives the results I want.

Answer (score 19):

You can use below line to mock `java.lang.reflect.Method`:

```
Method mockMethod = this.getClass().getMethod(methodName);
```

It is not allowed to use mock or spy in straight forward way to create a mock object for `java.lang.reflect.Method`!

Comment: This is way better ^. Thanks

Comment: Since Method is a final class so its not possible to mock it , better to pass the name of the method in the above way to the calling flow.