# How to mock Final Clases under java/androidTest using Mockito2?

Tags: android, class, testing, mockito, final

[image]Final classes can be mocked under java/test when I define in gradle:

> testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-inline:+"

How to mock final classes under java/androidTest? This solution does not work:

> androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-android:+"

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: It is not a duplication. I want to know if it is possible to do it for Android Platform.

Comment: Mockito behaviour should be identical between `test/` and `androidTest/`, the fact that you're running the tests on an Android device rather than a JVM should make no difference as it's not part of the Android framework.

Comment: Mockito 2 {testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:+" and    androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-android:+"
 } does not introduce mocking final classes. To do that instead of  org.mockito:mockito-core  I need to use org.mockito:mockito-inline:+. And it works fine for test/ but it does not for androidTest/. I am wondering what change do I need to do in order to enable it under androidTest package.

Comment: Use inline with connected tests by adding `androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-inline:+"`?

Comment: When I do that I receive an exception that for androidTestCompile I should use org.mockito:mockito-android:+. I found also a hint to add a file: java/com/(androidTest)resources/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker containing the value mock-maker-inline. But it does not work either.

Answer (score 8):

Mocking final classes is not supported for `mockito-android` as per [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1173).

From one of the library maintainers:

> There is no real possibility to make [mocking final classes] work in Android at the moment as it lacks the instrumentation API on top of which we are operating. The Android VM is not a standard VM and only implements a subset of the Java specification. As long as Google does not choose to extend its JVM, I am afraid that this feature will not work.

There are some options to replace it depending on your use case.

**Option 1: Use wrappers**

If you wish to mock a `final` Android system class like `BluetoothDevice` you can simply create a non-final wrapper around that class and consume the `BluetoothDeviceWrapper` in your code instead of the `BluetoothDevice`:

```
class BluetoothDeviceWrapper {

   private final BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;

   BluetoothDeviceWrapper(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice) {
       this.bluetoothDevice = bluetoothDevice;
   }

   public String getName() {
       return bluetoothDevice.getName();
   }
}
```

Pro tip: you can use Android Studio's `Generate / Delegate` methods to generate delegate methods like  `getName()` for you by pressing <kbd>Alt-Ins</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd-N</kbd> and choosing the correct option. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14292975/5241933) for a more detailed example.

**Option 2: use a testing framework like Robolectric**

[Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) provides working test doubles (called shadows) of Android classes like `Context` and `SQLiteDatabase`. You may be able to find a shadow of the class you are trying to mock in your test out of the box.

**Option 3: use DexOpener**

You can also try the library [DexOpener](https://github.com/tmurakami/dexopener) with the ability to mock final classes in Android.

Comment: Robolectric is the answer here.

Comment: I will try with wrappers, I started using espresso and i would like to stick to this android native framework. Thanks!

Comment: @JasonTholstrup What about E2E tests that should run on device with use of a library like Espresso? I think Option 3 is useful there.

Comment: If it's an E2E test wouldn't you not be mocking?

Answer (score 4):

You may now use [`dexmaker-mockito-inline`](https://github.com/linkedin/dexmaker).  See [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/mock-final-and-static-methods-on-android-devices-b383da1363ad) for details regarding variants of Mockito and their capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I just got a response that the final mock maker does not work on Android.

https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1173#issuecomment-324401986

Comment: Can we achieve the same using PowerMock?

Answer (score 0):

final classes, objects, constructors can all be mocked with mockk
https://mockk.io/