# How to mock/stub jOOQ UpdatableRecordImpl store() method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jooq

I already managed to stub update():

```
@Test
public void updateStubbed() {
    UpdatableRecordTest updatableRecordTest = spy(new UpdatableRecordTest());
    doReturn(1).when(updatableRecordTest).update();
}
```

However, when I try to stub store():

```
@Test
public void storeStubbed() {
    UpdatableRecordTest updatableRecordTest = spy(new UpdatableRecordTest());
    doReturn(1).when(updatableRecordTest).store();
}
```

I get the error:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue:
>   Integer
>   cannot be returned by fieldsRow() fieldsRow() should return Row
>
> ---
>
> If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on. Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
>
> 1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.    Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency
>      testing.
> 2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies -
>
>    - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.

How to stub **store()** method?

Comment: I have the same problem. Apparently it's impossible to mock `final` methods (such as `store()` with mockito unless you use mockito v2 and add special extension.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mock `store()` method with Mockito as it is a `final` method, and Mockito doesn't provide support for mocking final methods. What you can do, is:

- for unit tests, use PowerMock (which provides a way of mocking final methods, but is not Spring friendly. Just mentioning in case you work with Spring),
- for functional tests, create embedded DB schema, and configure your JOOQ to use this one in *testing* environment.

Unfortunately I don't have a better answer.

Comment: This is actually supported with a little extra help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292863/how-to-mock-a-final-class-with-mockito/40018295#40018295