# How to stub a Facebook's SDK access token for unit testing

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.x

I'm trying to perform some unit testing in my application and I've ran into a problem. A simple graph request demands an AccessToken object which can only be claimed by -

```
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
```

or getting it in an authentication result.
Both of the options requires a real authentication process with ui which makes it impossible to unit test. is there a way to create my own AccessToken object? I've tried to use reflection with no luck. any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You may use espresso to write UI test and must use real authentication token to test f.b sdk otherwise you must have to skip sdk login test.

Comment: awesome, saved my job

Comment: Well, skipping isn't an option, there's always the option to edit their jar locally and import it but this is a bad option so I'm seeking for other solutions

Answer (score 0):

if anynone needs a solutions for this problem I've managed to solve this by using Mockito's final classes extension. look at this answer for more details - [How to mock a final class with mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292863/how-to-mock-a-final-class-with-mockito/40018295#40018295/)