# Mock android.content.res.Configuration with mockito

Tags: java, android, mockito

When I mock `Configuration` I get an exception that I do not get when mocking other classes such as Resources.

`Configuration configuration = mock(Configuration.class);`

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
ClassCastException occurred while creating the mockito proxy :
  class to mock : 'android.content.res.Configuration', loaded by classloader : 'org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.InstrumentingClassLoader@57fffcd7'
  created class : 'android.content.res.Configuration$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$78c79839', loaded by classloader : 'org.mockito.internal.creation.util.SearchingClassLoader@e344ad3'
  proxy instance class : null
  instance creation by : ObjenesisInstantiator

You might experience classloading issues, disabling the Objenesis cache *might* help (see MockitoConfiguration)
```

I'm not super familar with mockitoi, can anyone advise me how I can properly mock the `Configuration` class?

Comment: try `Configuration configuration = Mockito.mock(Configuration.class);`

Comment: @a_local_nobody Thanks, but same error.

Comment: found a few other SO posts using that syntax so thought it might help, might just be a bug with the library

Answer (score 0):

As they said

> 'disabling the Objenesis cache might help'

You can create override MockitoConfiguration.
To do so

Create a package named org.mockito.configuration under your src/test/java
Write the `MockitoConfiguration` class

**Class File**

```
package org.mockito.configuration;

public class MockitoConfiguration extends DefaultMockitoConfiguration {

  @Override
  public boolean enableClassCache() {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [`this`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/res/Configuration.java) `android.content.res.Configuration` is a **final** class.

`Mockito` normally is unable to mock final classes. You might want to use `PowerMockito` instead.

---

Edit:
According to this [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292863/how-to-mock-a-final-class-with-mockito) there is an opt-in feature for `mockito` that I have not between aware of. It might be worth a try.

---

However since `PowerMockito` has the same issue, it might be something else completly that prevents it from working.

Comment: `PowerMockito.mock(Configuration.class);` gives the same error.

Comment: You added the correct class(es) to the `@PrepareForTest` annotation and used the correct `Runner`? If you can add a [mre] using PowerMockito  to your question.

Comment: Also note that there are some issues with the classloader of `roboelectrics` and the one `powermockito` and/or `mockito` is using, so that really might just be a variant of  a known issue.