# How to mock Abstract class method in a class to be tested

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit4, spy

There is an `abstract` class

```
public abstract class BaseProcessor {
 public BooksTransaction getBooksTransaction() {
        return booksTransaction;
    }
}
```

There is another `final class` which is to be tested using **Junit**

```
public final class CreateOrganisationProcessor extends BaseProcessor {

public boolean process() throws Exception { //method to be tested
        request = new CreateOrganisationRequest(IntegrationSystems.valueOf(getBooksTransaction().getSource()),
                IntegrationSystems.valueOf(getBooksTransaction().getDestination()), getBooksTransaction()); 
        request.setRequestTypes(getRequestTypes());
return true;
}
}
```

I tried **spying** the `BaseProcessor` class and **mocking** `getBooksTransaction` method to `return BooksTransaction` Object. 
**Code:**

```
@Test
   public void testProcess() throws Exception {
BaseProcessor spy = Mockito.spy(new CreateOrganisationProcessor());
       BooksTransaction booksTransaction = new BooksTransaction();
       booksTransaction.setReferenceID(DEFAULT_REFERENCE_ID);
       Mockito.doReturn(booksTransaction).when(spy).getBooksTransaction();
}
```

Here, `BooksTransaction` is an `JPA Entity` class.

However, when I run the test case, the mock does not seem to be working, it does not return a `BooksTransaction` Object. 
It neither throws an `exception`, nor any `error`.

I would like to know the right way to `spy` this method so that it returns me an object of `BooksTransaction` as per my `mock`.

I am new to `Mockito`, any help would be appreciable. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mocking of final class is not supported by default, but can be enabled if you use a mockito version that supports this feature. Check this [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40018295/11514534) and/or the [`faq`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#Mocking_Final) instead.

Comment: @second that `final` class _will_ result in a very specific error message; that the OP does not get.

Answer (score 1):

It's funny that you got 5 up-votes for a question that does not even compile to begin with... I have simplified it just a bit, so that I could *actually* compile it, since I do not know your structure or can't even guess it correctly.

But the very first point you should be aware of is that `Mockito` can't *by default* mock `final` classes; you have a comment under your question that shows how to enable that.

```
@Getter
static abstract class BaseProcessor {
    private BooksTransaction BooksTransaction;
}

@Getter
static class CreateOrganisationProcessor extends BaseProcessor {

    CreateOrganisationRequest request;

    public boolean process() { //method to be tested
        request = new CreateOrganisationRequest(getBooksTransaction());
        return true;
    }

    public CreateOrganisationRequest getRequest() {
        return request;
    }
}


@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
static class BooksTransaction {
    private final String testMe;
}

@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
static class CreateOrganisationRequest {
    private final BooksTransaction booksTransaction;
}
```

And here is a test that *does* work:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    CreateOrganisationProcessor org = new CreateOrganisationProcessor();
    CreateOrganisationProcessor spy = Mockito.spy(org);
    System.out.println(spy);
    BooksTransaction booksTransaction = new BooksTransaction("go!");

    Mockito.doReturn(booksTransaction).when(spy).getBooksTransaction();

    spy.process();
    BooksTransaction mocked = spy.getRequest().getBooksTransaction();
    Assert.assertEquals(mocked.getTestMe(), "go!");
}
```

And now think about it, you say in a comment : `//method to be tested` but you are not even calling it in your test, sounds fishy doesn't it? Than that method is defined in `CreateOrganisationProcessor`, but you are assigning your spy to:

```
 BaseProcessor spy = Mockito.spy(new CreateOrganisationProcessor());
```

So now you can't even call `process` anymore on that `spy` reference, since it is *not* defined in `BaseProcessor`.

Comment: I did not add the `assert` statement where I am calling process to keep the question short. 
There are a lot more mocks to be done before calling the process method. 
But the first line `getBooksTransaction` was throwing error which made me ask the question. 
I see that spy has been created on `CreateOrganisationProcessor` and not on `BaseProcessor`, what is the concept behind spy? could you explain in short please.  also, it throws `NPE` when i run this code. 
At `getBooksTransaction()` . When I evaluate the expression in intellij it says 'this' is not available.

Comment: @NiharikaDash see how much sense you make. on one hand you say _But the first line getBooksTransaction was throwing error which made me ask the question_ in the comment, but you say in the question: _It neither throws an exception, nor any error._ Then you go ahead to say: _also, it throws NPE when i run this code, followed by _When I evaluate the expression in intellij it says 'this' is not available._. There's like 10 different things you are talking about.