# Why mocking data returns null?

Tags: android, mocking, mockito, android-testing

I have this piece of code

```
 carouselGroupMock = mock(ApiCarouselGroup::class.java).apply {
      `when`(items).thenReturn(listOf("tvChannels", "featured"))
    }
```

and ApiCarouselGroup class 
is here

```
class ApiCarouselGroup @Throws(IOException::class)
constructor(jsonReader: JsonReader) : IApiPageLayoutComponent {
  var items: List<String>? = null

  init {
    jsonReader.beginObject()
    while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
      when (jsonReader.nextName()) {
        "items" -> this.items = JsonReaderUtil.readArray(jsonReader, String::class.java)
        else -> jsonReader.skipValue()
      }
    }
    jsonReader.endObject()
  }

  override fun toPresenterModel(): PageComponent.CarouselGroup {
    return PageComponent.CarouselGroup(items ?: emptyList())
  }
}

interface IApiPageLayoutComponent {
    fun toPresenterModel() : PageComponent

    companion object {
        val FACTORY : JsonReaderUtil.IObjectFactory<IApiPageLayoutComponent> = JsonReaderUtil.IObjectFactory<IApiPageLayoutComponent> {
            jsonReader ->
            val jsonObject = JsonReaderUtil.JSON_OBJECT_FACTORY.newInstance(jsonReader)
            when(jsonObject.getString("type")) {
                "heroBanners" -> ApiHeroBannerGroup(JsonReader(StringReader(jsonObject.toString())))
                "carousels" -> ApiCarouselGroup(JsonReader(StringReader(jsonObject.toString())))
                else -> null
            }
        };
    }
}
```

and the problem is items in carouselGroupMock is null

Just for information I want to mention I have this and it works no problem 
I don't understand what the problem in first case?

```
mainMenuMock = mock(ApiMainMenu::class.java).apply {)
      `when`(actions).thenReturn(listOf(actionMock))
    }
```

where ApiMainMenu

````
class ApiMainMenu @Throws(IOException::class)
constructor(jsonReader: JsonReader) {
  var type: String? = null
  var titles: List<ApiTitle>? = null
  var actions: List<ApiAction>? = null

  init {
    jsonReader.beginObject()
    while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
      when (jsonReader.nextName()) {
        "action" -> this.actions = JsonReaderUtil.readArray(jsonReader, ApiAction::class.java)
        else -> jsonReader.skipValue()
      }
    }
    jsonReader.endObject()
  }
}```
````

Comment: may i know what is `ApiCaraouselGroup` parent class which is it's name `IApiPageLayoutComponent` looks like?

Comment: I have updated @Nanda Z

Comment: i mean, what is `IApiPageLayoutComponent`, can you provide it too?

Comment: Sure,  I added .

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it really answer your question, but i think there is somewhere in your mock trying to invoke source from final class. 
have you added this dependency?

```
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.13.0' // for final class
```

Comment: Wasn't `mockito-inline` mainly used for `kotlin`? Check this [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40018295/11514534) and/or the [`faq`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#Mocking_Final) instead.