# Mockito cannot mock/spy because : Final Class

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito, mockito-kotlin

I know this question is asked a lot of time, but I followed a lot of answer and it still didnt work

[How to mock a final class with mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292863/how-to-mock-a-final-class-with-mockito)

in this link, they said that we have to add in our gradle :

```
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.13.0'
```

=> Currently I have

```
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.28.2"
```

I also have this single line in my MockMaker file :

```
mock-maker-inline
```

Then you can see my following code :

```
object ApiHelper {

fun <T> createService(
        url: String,
        clazz: Class<T>
    ): T
}
```

in my UITEST

```
    @Mock
    private lateinit var service: myService

    private lateinit var apiHelper: ApiHelper

    @Before
    fun setUp() {

        apiHelper = mock(ApiHelper::class.java)

        given(ApiHelper.createService(
            anyString(),
            MyService::class.java,
        )).willReturn(service)
    }
```

What is wrong with my code? Did I missed something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> mocking library for Kotlin http://mockk.io

I also used mockito before, it has so many problems when writing.

Instead, the mockk is powerful and it makes your testing easier to write and

[object mocks](https://mockk.io/#object-mocks) is just for your case

Answer (score 3):

This approach for mocking final classes unfortunately [doesn't work for UI tests](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1173). 
For your UI tests, you'll have to work with [the kotlin allopen plugin](https://proandroiddev.com/mocking-androidtest-in-kotlin-51f0a603d500).