# How to return SearchHits with SearchHits.getHits() (elasticsearch) for testing purposes?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, elasticsearch, mocking

The question in the title isn't so clear, but I could't find a more suitable title.
Currently I have to write tests (branch coverage) for a spring service (working with elasticsearch) and the method looks like this:

```
public CarSearchResult findCarData(final String name, final CarType carType){
     ....  search  .....
     return mapResponse(response);
}

private CarSearchResult mapResponse(final SearchResponse results) throws IOException {
   final CarSearchResult answer = new CarSearchResult();

   final List<Car> mappedCars = new LinkedList<>();

   for (SearchHit searchHit : results.getHits()) { <--  how to enter for-loop for testcoverage
       final CarObj carObj = map(searchHit);
       mappedCars.add(carObj );
   }
   answer.setCarObj(mappedCars);

   return answer;
}
```

mapResponse() gets the searchresults ([doc](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/latest/org/elasticsearch/action/search/SearchResponse.html)) and these are further processed.

Inside my test class I have something like this:

```
@Mock private SearchResponse searchResponse;

// other Test cases for empty result worked because of this (case not entering the for loop)
when(searchResponse.getHits()).thenReturn(SearchHits.empty());
```

The problem is due to branch coverage I want to write a test which covers the case of having hits as well.
But for this I would need Searchhits [(doc)](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/2.3.0/org/elasticsearch/search/SearchHits.html). **Does anybody know a way to enter this for-loop so branch coverage can be achieved?**

I tried to find a way to return searchhits with **when(searchResponse.getHits()).thenReturn( ..???.. )**, but I don't know (or couldn't find) what should be returned so that I can cover the for-loop.

Comment: You'd just return a mock of `SearchHits`… did you try that?

Comment: Do you mean when(searchResponse.getHits()).thenReturn(searchHits) (@Mock private SearchHits searchHits;)? I already tried this, but it leads to nullpointer exception

Comment: This is because you have to define the desired behavior of the mock… i.e. you have to mock the `iterator()` method.

Answer (score 2):

You have to return a mock of `SearchHits`, with the `iterator()` method being mocked (because that's what called behind the scenes in the `for` loop):

```java
@Mock SearchHits searchHits;
@Mock SearchHit searchHit;

when(searchHits.iterator()).thenReturn(singleton(searchHit).iterator());
when(searchHit.docId()).thenReturn(42);
```

Note that because both `SearchHits` and `SearchHit` are final classes you have to [ensure that Mockito is able to mock final classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292863).

Comment: what is `singleton(...)` used for here?