# How to Mock Config Provider Class ( org.eclipse.microprofile.config.ConfigProvider)

Tags: java, mockito, junit5, powermockito

I am using ConfigProvider.getConfig().getValue("myproject.some.remote.service.url", String.class);
from org.eclipse.microprofile.config .
when iam trying to mock the ConfigProvider class  getting org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException cannot mock/spy org.eclipse.microprofile.config.ConfigProvider. Need help in resolving the issue.

Comment: You are trying to mock a final class. You need to use the inline mock maker. Check the docs: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#39

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock a final class with mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292863/how-to-mock-a-final-class-with-mockito)

Answer (score 1):

we can mock ConfigProvider using mockito library by following the ways

```
public void testMethodWithMockConfigProvider(){ 
    Config config= mock(Config.class);
    try (MockedStatic<ConfigProvider> mockConfigProvider = Mockito.mockStatic(ConfigProvider.class)) {
        mockConfigProvider.when(()-> ConfigProvider.getConfig()).thenReturn(config);
        when(config.getValue(eq("myproject.some.remote.service.url"), any())).thenReturn("mockUrl");

}//try with resource close
}//end of method
```

Sometimes there may be needed to add dependencies for static methods. they are **junit5-mockito** and **mockito-inline**