# Android Jetpack compose how to test background color

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-testing

I have a composable that set the background color and I would like to test that.

```
@Composable
fun MyComposableButton(
    enabledColor: Color,
    disableColor: Color,
    isEnabled: Boolean = true,
) {
    val buttonBackgroundColor = if (enabled) enabledColor else disableColor
    Button(
        ...
        enabled = enabled,
        colors = ButtonDefaults.textButtonColors(
            backgroundColor = buttonBackgroundColor
        )
    ) { ... }
}
```

I'm expecting to write a tests like: `verifyEnabledBackgroundColor` and `verifyDisabledBakcgroundColor`.

I can't find any assertion directly available on the compose testing, and when trying to create my own I find that the `SemanticMatcther` uses a `SemanticNode`, but the constructor is internal for the latest so that is no go.

I try to `mock` the `Color` but I couldn't and according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66821282/4017501) high API level would be required, which is a no for my project.

How can I test setting the background color for a composable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To correct cutiko [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70682865/14705996) :

**Validating color of composable based on colorspace.name does not work since the returned value is just a name of the color space. In other words test will pass regardless of the actual color.**

Actual solution:

If the purpose of the test is to distinguish if the actual color of the composable is correct, for instance in a case where the color of a composable changes dynamically we need to use method .readPixels which provide "ARGB values packed into an Int. "

example usage:

```
val array = IntArray(20)
composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag(TestTags.CONTENT_TEXT_FIELD_TAG).captureToImage()
            .readPixels(array, startY = 500, startX = 200, width = 5, height = 4)
array.forEach { it shouldNotBe Colors().Red.convert(ColorSpaces.Srgb).hashCode() }
array.forEach { it shouldBe Colors().Pink.convert(ColorSpaces.Srgb).hashCode() }
```

Comment: It does seem to work, and you are right, my solution is wrong. I'm having problems with `readPixels`, can you please expand you answer to know why the arguments?

Comment: looks like he is taking/picking some arbitrary patch (5 by 4) of pixels from the captured image and comparing each pixel with the color. I tried this and got index out of bound, may be because my captured image is very small. So I ended up calling sth like \n
val img= captureToImage(); 
val pixel = img.asAndroidBitmap().getPixel(img.width/2, img.height/2); 
Assert.assertEquals(Color.Red.toArgb, pixel);

Answer (score 7):

[UPDATE] Please read the other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72629280/4017501

After a lot of trials and errors, I found a way to do it. There is an extension `captureImage` that has the color space. With that, we can find the color name and make an equal assertion.

It has some limitations though: it is the surface underlying the node, so multiple nodes or gradients maybe won't work.

```
fun SemanticsNodeInteraction.assertBackgroundColor(expectedBackground: Color) {
    val capturedName = captureToImage().colorSpace.name
    assertEquals(expectedBackground.colorSpace.name, capturedName)
}
```

I made an extension for reusability, for example:

```
composeTestRule.setContent {
    ...
}

composeTestRule.onNodeWithText(someText).assertBackgroundColor(YourColor)
```

Beware, this might be working because in the testing we are making sure to pass our theme:

```
composeTestRule.setContent {
    OurSuperCoolTheme { //your compose }
}
```

Comment: Man, it does not do the job :). It returns just the colorspace name which will be technically same for all colors. Test it with colors :).
Tested it, not working.

Comment: @Pietrek thanks for letting me know, going to take a look at it

Comment: no problem, if I find the solution I will post the answer here. Fingers crossed :)

Answer (score 3):

Not perfect, but allows me to know if an icon is tinted with the correct color. Based on previous answers.

```
fun SemanticsNodeInteraction.assertContainsColor(tint: Color): SemanticsNodeInteraction {
    val imageBitmap = captureToImage()
    val buffer = IntArray(imageBitmap.width * imageBitmap.height)
    imageBitmap.readPixels(buffer, 0, 0, imageBitmap.width - 1, imageBitmap.height - 1)
    val pixelColors = PixelMap(buffer, 0, 0, imageBitmap.width - 1, imageBitmap.height - 1)

    (0 until imageBitmap.width).forEach { x ->
        (0 until imageBitmap.height).forEach { y ->
            if (pixelColors[x, y] == tint) return this
        }
    }
    throw AssertionError("Assert failed: The component does not contain the color")
}
```

Comment: Seems a litle wastefull to iterate the entire view. So how is that working if the color of the component is different than the background?

Comment: No, this only tries to find a specific color in the composable, at any point. I use it for detecting the tint of icons that I change depending on some conditions. Is not that bad, at least with small composables.

Comment: Ho! I get it know! If any pixel matches, then is ok. Is it worthy for a comment, or was I just clueless?

Comment: I'm not very kin on comments. I prefer semantic names like `assertContainsColor`

Comment: Apples and oranges, but have as you please, is your answer

Answer (score 2):

Maybe is an old post, but you could use Semantics matchers.

First, you need to create a semantic property and an extension like this

```
val ColorRes = SemanticsPropertyKey<Color>("ColorRes")
var SemanticsPropertyReceiver.colorRes by ColorRes
```

Instead of use "ColorRes" you can use an explicit name to specify which background color is,something like "CardBackgroundColor".

Then create a Matcher

```
fun hasBackgroundColor(expectedBackgroundColor: Color) =
    SemanticsMatcher.expectValue(ColorRes, expectedBackgroundColor)
```

Then add a semantic modifier to the composable like this

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
                .testTag("someTestTag")
                .semantics {
                    colorRes = theColorYouWant
                }
    )
```

and finally create the test

```
@Test
fun `Assert the background color`() {
//Some code to setContent ...
        composeTestRule
            .onNode(
                hasTestTag("deviceSignalContainer") and hasBackgroundColor(YourColor.Red),
                useUnmergedTree = true
            ).assertIsDisplayed()
    }
```

And that's all.

Comment: The problem is you have to modify the compose component code. If someone misses the new convention and uses `Modifier.background` as is standard it won't work. And it brings specific problems with other components like: what is going to happen with `Surface` or `Card` those components have to use the background color in the argument function, it can not be provided via `modifier`. It is good to have alternatives, though.

Comment: well, will be necessary to use an explicit name, instead of "colorRes" you can use "backgroundColorRes" or "SurfaceBackgroundColorRes" depends of the necesity.

Answer (score 0):

Based on :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70682865/19411871
and
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72629280/19411871

i did this:

```
fun SemanticsNodeInteraction.assertBackgroundColor(expectedBackground: Color) {
    val array = IntArray(20)
    captureToImage()
        .readPixels(
            array,
            startY = 100,
            startX = 200,
            width = 5,
            height = 4
        )
    array.forEach {
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedBackground.convert(ColorSpaces.Srgb).hashCode(), it)
}
```