# Azure Tables and Blobs Tests

Tags: spring-boot, azure, unit-testing, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage

So I'm trying to do Azure Tables and Blobs tests related to service I'm implementing. But when I do the tests it says 'Cannot mock TableServiceClient / TableClient because they are final classes' (same happens with blobs). Also, when using Autowired it gets detected as null.

The next is the code I'm trying to test, but the main issue is that cannot mock TableClient and TableServiceClient, so I cannot use or emulate the usage of the tables I have created.

```
@Service
public class AzureServicesTables implements PreferencesPersistenceService {
    public final TableServiceClient tableServiceClient;
  
    private final String PARTITION_KEY = "PartitionKey";

    @Autowired
    public AzureStoragePreferencesPersistenceServiceImpl(TableServiceClient tableServiceClient) {
        this.tableServiceClient = tableServiceClient;
    }

    /**
     * This method obtains preferences from Azure Table Storage, returning default preferences
     * when user has no setup. The steps are:
     *  - Get user preferences from Azure Table
     *  - If user preferences are null, get default preferences
     */
    public String getUserPreferencesField(String user) {
        TableClient tableClient = this.tableServiceClient.getTableClient("Preferences");

        // Query of user preferences
        TableEntity entity = null;
        try {
            entity = tableClient.getEntity(PARTITION_KEY, user);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            // Exception has to be voided in order to get default preferences
            LOGGER.info("User preferences not found: "+ex.getClass().getName());
        }
        // or default preferences if the user has no preferences defined
        if (entity == null) {
            entity = tableClient.getEntity(PARTITION_KEY, "default");
        }

        // Getting preferences values from entity
        String result = String.valueOf(entity.getProperties().get("value"));
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Saves full preferences for the specified user
     * @param user User to which preferences belongs
     * @param preferences Preferences to be saved
     */
    private Preferences savePreferences(String user, String preferences) {
        PreferencesEntity entity = new PreferencesEntity(PARTITION_KEY, user, preferences);
        TableClient tableClient = this.tableServiceClient.getTableClient("Preferences");
        tableClient.upsertEntity(entity.toTableEntity());
        return entity.getPreferences();
    }

    /**
     * This method obtains preferences from Azure Table Storage, returning default preferences
     * when user has no setup. The steps are:
     *  - Get user preferences from Azure Table
     *  - If user preferences are null, get default preferences
     *  - Deserialize preferences to return DTO
     * @param user The user which user preferences belongs to
     * @return User preferences for the specified user
     */
    @Override
    public Preferences getUserPreferences(String user) {
        // JSON deserialization of user preferences
        return Preferences.buildFromJson(
                this.getUserPreferencesField(user));
    }

    /**
     * This method sets one specified user preference to the value specified. The resulting
     * preferences are validated before being saved.
     *
     * @param user The user to which the preferences belong to
     * @param preference Preference to be set
     * @param value Value to be set to the preference
     * @return Preferences which belongs to the user once modified
     */
    @Override
    public Preferences setUserPreference(String user, String preference, String value) {
        // Value assignment for user preferences. It is done this way, instead of getting value String
        // directly in order to have all the properties in the JSON object, not only that have been
        // specifically put on current preferences.
        DocumentContext jsonPreferences = JsonPath.parse(
                this.getUserPreferences(user).jsonString());
        jsonPreferences.set("$.."+preference, value);

        // Preferences persistence on database
        return this.savePreferences(user, jsonPreferences.jsonString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292863/how-to-mock-a-final-class-with-mockito

Comment: yes! now I can Mock them, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 'Cannot mock TableServiceClient / TableClient because they are final classes.

- Thanks @dcolazin, As dcolazin said it appears that there are the ways to mock final classes or methods directly with Mockito. Thanks dcolazin.

**Dependencies**:

```
<!-- Mockito dependency -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- JUnit dependency (if not already included) -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.13.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

- Add the above Mockito library to your project dependencies and configure it correctly in your testing environment.

Check the below code to use Mockito to mock classes and methods.

```java
import org.mockito.Mockito;

// Create a mock instance of your class
TableServiceClient tableServiceClientMock = Mockito.mock(TableServiceClient.class);
TableClient tableClientMock = Mockito.mock(TableClient.class);

// Define your expected behavior for the mocks
when(tableServiceClientMock.getTableClient("Preferences")).thenReturn(tableClientMock);

// Now, invoke your method under test and perform assertions
AzureServicesTables azureServicesTables = new AzureServicesTables(tableServiceClientMock);
String result = azureServicesTables.getUserPreferencesField("user");
```

- The ability to mock final classes or methods with Mockito may depend on the version of Mockito you are using and the specific setup of your project.

here is the sample tutorial that how he configured [Mockito](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-final#final-method)

**Second approach:**

- Have you check this "[How to mock a final class with mockito](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/java/how-to-mock-a-final-class-with-mockito.html#:%7E:text=class%20public%20class%20TestClass%20%7B%20%40,order%20to%20use%20this%20approach.)"
- [GitHub - powermock/powermock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock)

Comment: We **can** directly mock final classes or methods using popular mocking libraries like Mockito, at least since 7 years ago.

Comment: Thanks @dcolazin for the information you given. I have updated the above answer and added some more insights.